# Traefik configuration to allow websocket and https on the same port of a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, traefik, registrator

I have a docker container (nginx) which expose only 1 port 443. This container listens to protocoles *wss* and *https*.

I need to configure my docker-compose file to push informations to my consul catalog. How can I put informations to add these 2 protocoles ?

```
*docker-compose.yml*:
    nginx:
      labels:
        SERVICE_443_NAME: ws-name
        SERVICE_443_TAGS: 'traefik.protocol=wss,traefik.frontend.entryPoints=wss,traefik.frontend.rule=Host:web.mydomain.com;Path=/ws'
```

Have you any idea to add *https* protocol on the same *SERVICE_TAGS* ?

For information, my architecture is : traefik -> consul catalog -> registrator -> container nginx

Answer (score 1):

Replace `traefik.protocol=wss` by `traefik.protocol=https`.
And use the a simple `https` entrypoint named `https`.

Comment: Ok but if I do this one, I will only have https. So how can I have the 2 protocoles described ?

Comment: @Idez thank you. The problem was with an older version of traefik. I have tested with the last version and it's ok now.